# How to create object from given Path?

Tags: typescript

Similarly to `_.set` I want create object from given `Path`.

For example:

```
type Path = readonly ['a', 'b'];
type Object = SOMETHING<Path, {c: "foo"}>; // {a: {b: {c: "foo" } } }
```

Any ideas how to get such behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a recursive conditional type that traverses the path tuple:

```
type KeyPath = readonly PropertyKey[]
type SOMETHING<P extends KeyPath, T> =
  P extends readonly [infer Key, ...infer Rest]
  ? {[K in Extract<Key, PropertyKey>]: SOMETHING<Extract<Rest, KeyPath>,T>}
  : T 

type Path = readonly ['a', 'b'];
type Obj = SOMETHING<Path, {c: "foo"}>; // {a: {b: {c: "foo" } } }
```

The `Extract` applications are necessary as the inferred arguments will not automatically have the right constraints. The `Extract<Rest, KeyPath>` could be removed if the `extends KeyPath` is dropped from `SOMETHING`, but would remove the tuple check on the path argument.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIAUCGwAWUC8UBOEkBMB7AOwBsQoFtDJtQ4QBtAXQChRIoBlAeQFkAogBUAEgEkAcgHEAPAigQAHsAjF8AZ1jxkaADRQhAPkysolBctUaceImQqMAlsQBmEbFpD6AdL%20duPACUIdWA2MwB%20KABvRhgoZygBZWwkAGNgGQZ9Khp3enhDZgAubn5hcWkZZOBUjJlg0P0GHVRDXSMAX1MoUqEoVnZwaFbMGwIScihGAHIkGf0ZgCMZ5gBuIc4eJYArMd5BUUlZVv1otNKAIhdCQkvOwzWoAHpnmKRS6KXPi6hr28uUE6QKBrCAA)

Comment: Thanks, I have another question, maybe you know answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67355756/infer-real-type-from-generic-function?