# Infer real type from generic function

Tags: typescript

I have two opposite types:
`Path` which picks type from object, for example:

```
Path<['a', 'b'], { a: { b: number } }> // returns number type
```

And `ObjPath` which creates object from key path, for example:

```
Path<['a'], { b: number }> // returns {a: {b: number }} type
```

But when I try to use these types in function with generic params for some reason I get generic types, not real one.

```
function someFunction<
  P extends KeyPath,
  O extends ObjPath<
    P,
    {
      foo: number;
    }
  >
>(props: { object: O; prefix: P }) {
  type Result = Path<P, O>; // actual type P extends readonly [infer Key, ...infer Rest] ? Path<Extract<Rest, KeyPath>, O[Extract<Key, PropertyKey>]> : O
  // but I except {foo: number} here
}
```

How to get real type here?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=27&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIAUCGwAWUC8UBOEkBMB7AOwBsQoFtDJtQ4QBtAXQG4Aod0SKAeQCMAVsjQAeBFAgAPYBGL4AzrHgjUAGigAVAHyZKkmXMU48RMhUYBLYgDMI2ZSA0A6V9bsOAShAXBm7KCgAfigAbyhGGChrKABRGWwkAGNgUQYNKhp7enhtZgAuPiFVUXjgRJTRb18NBlVtDR0oAF8AqELNDi5waBK2iWlZeSU6lHU2zQMh43DGAGto4kpqWhyQAqgkYgpW3SwBw2GTAhJyCPd7Rxc3W0vqvzaQkrKK1PvalTGGrUYX5NT0sssnQQAw8to2h0uuwbABXYgpSwkKAKQgAWwgADF4YiSKJ%20lMjCNPmg1G1eISjgJhGN8YFAggyfSwm1mTZCIRCsRYWj%20PYOMzWoEIdoABRgFYKQrhQhCCApQq8VhQCUQGyWKSFCTNACULMC3Gg1VhpGAehKjL42mVAHobZsUrCkKQoIb9IMicczGcrLcHIDXM4Ll4fH5gpRaX9Ku9HPUNLxfgl-ml4BkVtlQblmLpFW07VB%20LCzQBJAxJCBgM2hdmcqDc3n2ZpQVD2CDsVpAA)

Comment: I'm afraid these kinds of simplifications are beyond what TypeScript will be able to infer, as it would need to prove that the simplification holds for every `P` and `O` with those constraints.

Comment: I agree with @Oblosys. Honestly, I don't think it is good idea to define types inside function. I don't have any arguments against that, but it is seems for me a wrong direction

Comment: I don't want define types inside function, it's just example to show actual type of property.