# Typescript: accessing interface subtypes with square brackets... problem with optional properties

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Body {
    size: number;
    meta?: Meta;
}

export interface Request {
    body?: Body;
}
```

I thought that this will work:

```js
type MyMeta = Request["body"]["meta"];
```

However, because `body` is optional, type of `Request["body"]` is `Body | undefined`, so I'm getting

```
Property 'meta' does not exist on type 'Body | undefined'.ts(2339)
```

Is there any other way than things like:

```js
type MyMeta = Exclude<Request["body"], undefined>["meta"];
```

```js
type MyMeta = Required<Request>['body']['meta'];
```

?

Those will be problematic for deeper properties.

Using `DeepRequired` generic is also bad idea, now every property in `meta` is required:

```js
export type DeepRequired<T> = Required<{
    [K in keyof T]: DeepRequired<T[K]>
}>

type MyMeta =  DeepRequired<Request>['body']['meta'];
```

Comment: Would something like this be useful? https://tsplay.dev/WJ4z5N If so, I can write up an answer.

Comment: @Oblosys Best solution so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a recursive type `Index` that takes an array of keys and traverses the object type while discarding `undefined` alternatives:

```
type Index<P, T> = 
  P extends readonly [infer Key, ...infer Rest]
  ? T extends undefined ? never : Index<Rest, T[Extract<Key, keyof T>]>
  : T
```

Because `Index` doesn't constrain the path type, it will simply yield `never` for incorrect paths. This can be remedied by declaring a `Shape` type that builds and object with optional keys for each of the path keys (stolen from my answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/67351133/5770132, see that answer for more details).

```
type Shape<P> =
  P extends readonly [infer Key, ...infer Rest]
  ? {[K in Extract<Key, PropertyKey>]?: Shape<Rest>}
  : unknown
```

Using `Shape`, we can declare a `DeepIndex` that gives an error on incorrect paths:

```
type DeepIndex<T extends Shape<Path>, Path extends readonly PropertyKey[]> = Index<Path, T>
```

A few examples (with an added definition for `Meta`):

```
interface Meta { x: 42, meta: Meta }

interface Body { size: number; meta?: Meta }

export interface Request { body?: Body }

{ type Test = DeepIndex<Request, ['body']> }
// type Test = Body | undefined

{ type Test = DeepIndex<Request, ['body', 'size']> }
// type Test = number

{ type Test = DeepIndex<Request, ['body', 'meta', 'x']> }
// type Test = 42

{ type Test = DeepIndex<Request, ['body', 'meta', 'meta', 'meta', 'x']> }
// type Test = 42

{ type Test = DeepIndex<Request, ['nobody', 'size']> }
// ERROR: Type 'Request' has no properties in common with type
//        '{ nobody?: { size?: unknown; } | undefined; }
```

Note that the result includes `undefined` if the last property is optional, but won't automatically do so if any of the preceding properties are optional. Propagating optionality down the path would be possible but complicates things quite a bit. Removing `undefined` from the result is also possible, but that would return `never` for properties that happen to have the type `undefined` (which are probably not that common though).

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0gHgAoD4oF4BQUqpQQAewEAdgCYDOUAThApQPbkA2IUA2gJbkBmEOlADSEEABooAOll9BwgEoRqwALp4oAfigBvLiKh8oAUVJ0EAY2DIxkgnWaQ6oO%20jVaAXLEQplq9ABfTW8AV3IAa3JmAHdyKBwcUEgoAEkqEjQpABVMLAT8QhIyKloGJlYObnkhUXEpWWkapRV1TR1solIKGihwygh%20PghKbShyCAA3Wu90geJkf2AcrjNgC2tbeqgI8WZ%20KFy1dBDDhKTwaAARCAgwOczO4p7aeCQINARgOHQpVC%204F0Sr1yix2JxUI5nK5xFxjtg0hkFv9vjkTjg%20GQ6PwrNAALIQYAIPRQYjeAAsACYpABbQkIbwEolQYIY8hYnGWaAAIWYlE4uig1B4AC8IN5yKEaQAjIQAbigdKJXigTOJrJIYGYLiM7KEnOgygAjqFWiTpXyQCrefyWYlBcloNkzfkbncHgtjabVFIuAByC38v3w4IAelD%20EjAD0tDgHZdDi6oG77kjFhATa1fQHLX6pH7hWLg5gwxHI1AY3GoI7E6oESmPenMz7uDmg-mlQg81A-cRi3bw%20WK7H4ylnXXXbdU-Mm97lq3AyBu37O8vVx36cu%20yGcIPy5XR06kw2016s63oovl4WIP3S4cE36z6o-VBELRolAwFChMAeCpdSgSxmBpGlWCgGIeG%20atH0FS9LRVQUbxVcIolicgFUCKAAB8%20gyIYJkoTCcCAA)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in `NonNullable` type which is just an alias for `Exclude<T, undefined | null>`:

```
interface Body {
    size: number;
    meta?: { __notSpecified: never };
}

export interface Request {
    body?: Body;
}

type MyMeta = NonNullable<Request["body"]>["meta"]; // { __notSpecified: never; } | undefined
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAmBPZBvAKGWOQGdgAvCALmRAFcBbAI2gG4iTGIw4B+WnmQB9YSHRgAygAcICYDGARMtEBABu0ZAF8O2ggQgAPaeihhkoSLEQoAShACO9CKQuESyZlmwC0PvQMwbFlkAFlsMJ44ZABeZAA5dBAE+gAbNLhmNIgAHgdnVzAAbQAibxxSgF0APjLuXmq2ZAB6FvwRMQkZOQUlFToNdh1kAB9kehBMCEU1TCA)

Other than that, though, there's really nothing else you can do.